# Update textField value connected to a setAttr

Tags: python, maya

I'm a bit new in scripting and french so exuse me if my explanations are not perfectly clear.

I'm trying to make a script in Maya to manage easily the keys value for animation.

So I created a window reproducing Maya's ChannelBox with another organisation. And now I'm trying to set and upadate automaticaly the attribute values of selected object inside the different textField (transX, transY..).

I found some informations about a command called scriptJob that could help me, but didn't find any context looking like mine or recent informations about how to place it inside my code.

Here is what I have for now :

```
transX_value = cmds.textField( w=100 , h=22 , tx= cmds.getAttr("%s.translateX" %selected[0]) )
```

So now I'd need some help about connecting an update function inside my textField, so when it change and press Enter, the attribute would change too so I think that I need to insert a scriptJob inside my function but I don't know how.

```
def updateValues () :

for sel in selection :
    sel_attr = cmds.getAttr("%s+.name" %selected[0])
    cmds.setAttr( "%s+.name" , textField)
```

The end of the code is not right of course.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I've deleted my previous message about cmds.attrControlGrp(), cmds.attrFieldGrp() because it is beginning to make lots of posts xd. It could work fine but instead of updating attr value on selection, you would have rebuild the ui on selection change. It's a different approach.

Comment: I've added some correction, for the script job part, I can't test it here. My environment settings are in conflict I think

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I've tried to put you an example with lots of comments. Ask any question about it. I have put the script job into ''' '''. You will have to find out what will work for you.

```
import maya.cmds as cmds
from functools import partial

# Update Value
# I've changed the function and add the var attr to be more procedural
# and i've added *args, because command flags in maya add a default last argument True that
# is not useful
def updateValue (name, attr, *args) :    
    value = cmds.textField(name, query=True, text=True)
    #I've added the attr to be more procedural
    cmds.setAttr("%s.%s" %(selected[0], attr), float(value))

wName = "Key_Manager"
# Not enough protected varaible selected : should be inside a dic or a variable name more complicated
# as : Key_Manager_sel = cmds.ls(selection=True)
# see forward in the end on the update method
selected = cmds.ls(selection=True)

# Make a new window
#
if cmds.window(wName , exists = 1) : cmds.deleteUI(wName)

window = cmds.window( wName, s=0)
form = cmds.formLayout (wName +'Form')

# your attr should be not harcoded, see line 29, in order to be procedural
attr = 'translateX'
# Translate
# Create only one element one layout to place in your formLayout
wdgSetField = cmds.rowLayout(numberOfColumns=2)
# for ui nomenclature, i use lb_ for label or text (in Qt, it is cmds.text is a QLabel)
# attr[0].upper() is your 'T' and attr[1:] is : 'ranslateX' 
lb_Tx = cmds.text ( l=attr[0].upper() + attr[1:] ,  fn="boldLabelFont", p=wdgSetField)
# same here i would use a prefix because it is not really your value tx
# as haggi krey told you, you have to attach the function in a second part in order to have the name of the textField
transX_value = cmds.textField( w=100 , h=22 , tx= cmds.getAttr("%s.%s" %(selected[0], attr)), p=wdgSetField)
cmds.textField(transX_value, edit=True, ec = partial(updateValue, transX_value, attr))

# Just attach it to the form layout
cmds.formLayout( form , e=1 , attachForm = [ (wdgSetField , 'top' , 45) , (wdgSetField, 'left' , 50 ) ] )
# from line 17 to 28, should be a def because you will repeat this code for many attributes :
'''
def widget_attr(attr, pos=list):
    """
    parameter:: attr:: <str> long name of an attr, ie : 'translateX'
    parameter:: pos:: <list> [45, 50] take exactly two integer
    """
    wdgSetField = cmds.rowLayout(numberOfColumns=2, p=form)
    lb_attr = cmds.text ( l=attr[0].upper() + attr[1:] ,  fn="boldLabelFont", p=wdgSetField)
    le_value = cmds.textField( w=100 , h=22 , tx= cmds.getAttr("%s.%s" %(selected[0], attr)), p=wdgSetField)
    cmds.textField(le_value, edit=True, ec = partial(setValue, le_value, attr))
    cmds.formLayout( form , e=1 , attachForm = [ (wdgSetField , 'top' , pos[0]) , (wdgSetField, 'left' , pos[1] ) ] )
    # return the line edit for futur use, it is just here for knowledge (your can return a list of items too)
    return [attr, le_value]

# Why using dictionnary ? it could be a list but if you want to update every value on selection change,
# you will have to store this textField somewhere
ui_dic = {}
ui_dic['tx_prm'] = widget_attr('translateX', [45, 50])
ui_dic['ty_prm'] = widget_attr('translateY', [90, 100])
ui_dic['rx_prm'] = widget_attr('rotateX', [140, 50])

def updateTextField(selected):
    # Loop through the textField
    for k in ui_dic.keys():
        # in theory, i could just take 'tx_prm' and strip _prm  to find the attr but :
        attr =  ui_dic[k][0]
        le_Name = ui_dic[k][1]
        value = cmds.getAttr("%s.%s" %(selected[0], attr))
        cmds.textField(le_Name, e=True, text=str(value))

def setValue(name, attr, *args):
    value = cmds.textField(name, query=True, text=True)
    cmds.setAttr("%s.%s" %(selected[0], attr), float(value))

# For the script Job Part :

def onChangeSel():
    selected = cmds.ls(selection=True)
    updateTextField(selected)

# On selection change, update selection and textField
scriptJobID = cmds.scriptJob(e=["SelectionChanged", onChangeSel], protected=True)
# Script Job need to be deleted when the ui is closed or they will stack :
scriptJobWinClose()

def scriptJobWinClose():
    # create another scriptJob that will run once when the ui will be closed and run the function :
    cmds.scriptJob(runOnce=True, uid=[wName, closeEvent])

def closeEvent():
    # We just kill the scriptJob here but you could do really anything you want on the window closing  
    cmds.scriptJob(kill=scriptJobID, force=True)
'''


# Show Window
cmds.window( wName,e=1)
cmds.showWindow(window)
```

--- EDIT ---

```
import maya.cmds as cmds
from functools import partial

def updateTextField(selected):
    # Loop through the textField
    for k in ui_dic.keys():
        # in theory, i could just take 'tx_prm' and strip _prm  to find the attr but :
        attr =  ui_dic[k][0]
        le_Name = ui_dic[k][1]
        value = cmds.getAttr("%s.%s" %(selected[0], attr))
        cmds.textField(le_Name, e=True, text=str(value))

def setValue(name, attr, *args):
    value = cmds.textField(name, query=True, text=True)
    cmds.setAttr("%s.%s" %(selected[0], attr), float(value))

wName = "Key_Manager"
# Not enough protected varaible selected : should be inside a dic or a variable name more complicated
# as : Key_Manager_sel = cmds.ls(selection=True)
# see forward in the end on the update method
selected = cmds.ls(selection=True)

# Make a new window
#
if cmds.window(wName , exists = 1) : cmds.deleteUI(wName)

window = cmds.window( wName, s=0)
form = cmds.formLayout (wName +'Form')

def widget_attr(attr, pos=list):
    """
    parameter:: attr:: <str> long name of an attr, ie : 'translateX'
    parameter:: pos:: <list> [45, 50] take exactly two integer
    """
    wdgSetField = cmds.rowLayout(numberOfColumns=2, p=form)
    lb_attr = cmds.text ( l=attr[0].upper() + attr[1:] ,  fn="boldLabelFont", p=wdgSetField)
    le_value = cmds.textField( w=100 , h=22 , tx= 0, p=wdgSetField)
    cmds.textField(le_value, edit=True, ec = partial(setValue, le_value, attr))
    cmds.formLayout( form , e=1 , attachForm = [ (wdgSetField , 'top' , pos[0]) , (wdgSetField, 'left' , pos[1] ) ] )
    # return the line edit for futur use, it is just here for knowledge (your can return a list of items too)
    return [attr, le_value]

# Why using dictionnary ? it could be a list but if you want to update every value on selection change,
# you will have to store this textField somewhere
ui_dic = {}
ui_dic['tx_prm'] = widget_attr('translateX', [45, 50])
ui_dic['ty_prm'] = widget_attr('translateY', [90, 100])
ui_dic['tz_prm'] = widget_attr('translateZ', [150, 100])
ui_dic['rx_prm'] = widget_attr('rotateX', [200, 50])
# You can add any other textfied parameter like scaleX...etc


'''
# For the script Job Part :

def onChangeSel():
    selected = cmds.ls(selection=True)
    updateTextField(selected)

# On selection change, update selection and textField
scriptJobID = cmds.scriptJob(e=["SelectionChanged", onChangeSel], protected=True)
# Script Job need to be deleted when the ui is closed or they will stack :
scriptJobWinClose()

def scriptJobWinClose():
    # create another scriptJob that will run once when the ui will be closed and run the function :
    cmds.scriptJob(runOnce=True, uid=[wName, closeEvent])

def closeEvent():
    # We just kill the scriptJob here but you could do really anything you want on the window closing  
    cmds.scriptJob(kill=scriptJobID, force=True)
'''


# Show Window
cmds.window( wName,e=1)
cmds.showWindow(window)
updateTextField(selected)
```

Comment: I'm taking a look at it, but the second parts seems a bit complicated with my knowledge, I'm decrypting all the informations you gave me, thanks a lot for your help, this is very intresting.
For now, I don't really understand how `attr[0].upper()` could refer to the 'T' as `attr = 'translateX'` isn't a list ?
And then what is the point to set `attr='translateX'` as I need my attr to mean translateX, or translateY or rotate Z depending on the testField I'm inside ?

Comment: I get what you meant to do in the second part, I did a try making the first part as command and second part active, but it seem to lead to an empty as I get this error : `RuntimeError: file <maya console> line 49: Object 'Key_Manager|Key_ManagerForm|rowLayout12|textField35' not found. #`

Comment: On another hand, I wonder how to make the `def updateTextField(selected):` procedural, as for now it must be connected to chosen elements of the list, does that mean that I have to set multiple `def updateTextField` refering to [0],[1] and [2],[3]... ?

Comment: when the selection change, it triggered onChangeSel() which get the new object and then do the updateTextField (which update every textField with ui_dic dictionnary) So no, you don't have to write other def

Comment: for the attr[0].upper(), a text string is list in python. And why you want to separate translateX. Because you can do a 'for loop' to create ['translateX','translateY', 'translateZ', 'rotateX']

Comment: i edited a second example where i've deleted your part (it is just missing, the scriptjob part)

Comment: Oh ok, I didn't get how the loop was working with the dictionnary, I get it with your edited version. I'm trying to mix out your advices with my initial script which have some more elements working with a less optimised code.
Thanks a lot for all your explanations, I don't have all the logic of this way of thinking, but it's very intresting !
The last thing I didn't get is how is working `%s.%s` ? The function `setValue` isn't working, I though it should be `cmds.setAttr("%s.le_Name"%(selected[0], attr , float(value))` as I'm trying to do `cmds.setAttr("%s.translateX%(selected[0], attr..`?

Comment: First for string formating : '%s.%s'%('objName', 'translateX') will replace the first %s by the first variable 'objName' and the second %s by the second variable 'translateX' and give as result : 'objName.translateX'. So the function setValue is setting your object 'selected[0]' and not the ui textField 'le_Name'. And attr variable will put translateX, translateY or whatever. Put some print() and use my second example to see how data are passed.

Comment: Yes in fact. So I'm wondering why the `set value` function isn't working when pressing enter ? I'm reading more about the `partial` function you used for the `enter command` of the textField. But everything seems right..

Comment: have you an error appearing. if not,put some print into setValue to check variables. I have used the second version on three sphere and it was working

Comment: Sorry I was working on some other projects. No error appeared and no way to print anything with the setValue function or the updateTextField (I tried a simple `print "hello"`) but the scriptJob part works perfectly. I'm doing some tests to find out what's wrong. I used the second version too, and I'm working on Maya 2018 can it be the origin of the problem ?

Comment: Are you copy/paste the script and it is not working ? I don't see why it would bug in maya 2018. Track the dictionnary info, I can't check but it might be nested variable problem. Glad that the scriptJob is working ! Dont forgot to validate the answer if it answering you question or/and upvote posts that you found useful !

Comment: Yep I just copy-paste it, I take a look at the dictionnary and variables. Thanks a lot for your help and your explanations, you helped me a lot to understand more about scripting. I would have upvote your posts, but I don't have enough reputation.. I'm pretty new on this site..

Answer (score 1):

You have some problems in your code. I try to explain what could be improved.

```
import maya.cmds as cmds

wName = "Key_Manager"
selected = cmds.ls(selection=True)

if cmds.window(wName , exists = 1) : cmds.deleteUI(wName)

window = cmds.window( wName, s=0)
form = cmds.formLayout (wName +'Form')

translateMenu = cmds.text ( l='TranslateX' ,  fn="boldLabelFont")
```

**translateMenu** is really misleading, it is a simple label. If you return to your code after some time, you may not immediatly know what that means bedcause you can have menus in your window as well.

```
cmds.formLayout( form , e=1 , attachForm = [ (translateMenu , 'top' , 45) , (translateMenu, 'left' , 50 ) ] )

transX_value = cmds.textField( w=100 , h=22 , tx= cmds.getAttr("%s.translateX" %selected[0]) , ec = 'updateValue( "Key_Manager|translateX|transX" )' )
```

Hardcoding a UI element is not a good idea. In maya you never know if your UI elements are always named the same way. You can solve this by seperating the textField creation in two commands:

```
transX_value = cmds.textField( w=100 , h=22 , tx= cmds.getAttr("%s.translateX" %selected[0]))
cmds.textField(transX_value, edit=True, ec = 'updateValue("%s")'%transX_value)
```

And you could use a floatField instead of a textField what seems to be more appropriate in this case.

```
cmds.formLayout( form , e=1 , attachForm = [ (transX_value , 'top' , 68) , (transX_value , 'left' , 50 ) ] )

cmds.window( wName,e=1)
cmds.showWindow(window)

def updateValue (name) :    
    name = name.split('|')
    name = name[-1]
    attr = name.split('|')
    attr = name[1]

    cmds.setAttr ("%s + .attr" %selected, name+'_value'.text.getAttr('value'))
```

The **updateValue()** can never work for some reasons. What you want to do is to retreive the value from the text field and apply it to the object.
Let's imagine you used the improved version with the ec - command:

```
def updateValue (name) :    
    value = cmds.textField(name, query=True, text=True)
```

No need to split anything, just use the name to get the value:

```
cmds.setAttr ("%s + .attr" %selected, name+'_value'.text.getAttr('value'))
```

You try to assign the value to the object, but use use a list (selection is a list) and there is nothing called "attr". So the first part would be:

```
cmds.setAttr("%s.translateX"%selected[0]....
```

In the second part you mix object oriented approach with the maya specific text approach (use pymel if you want to use objects). So this is more appropriate:

```
cmds.setAttr("%s.translateX"%selected[0], float(value))
```

The float() is needed becuse you use a textField and not a floatField.

Hope tis helps a bit.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I'm trying to decript a little bit and doind some tests.
First, what do you mean by "Hardcoding" ? (".. an UI element is not a good idea")
Then, what I meant to do by spliting was to make it more procedural because I will have transX, Y, Z rotX so 9 entities using the same method.
So when I split the name, I'm trying to make so

`%s +.attr" %selected[0] = %s.translateX%selected[0]`

As I'm in the translateX textField, but it would be

`%s+.attr"%selected[0] = %s.rotateZ%selected[0]`
If I was inside the Rotate Z testField.

Answer (score 0):

That came out wrong.

At a first step, I need to find out how to update the attribute when the tx changes.
And at a second step I need to auto update the values if I select another object.

By the way, I found more about enterCommand in fact and try something like this, which isn't working..

```
transX_value = cmds.textField( w=100 , h=22 , tx= cmds.getAttr("%s.translateX" %selected[0]) , ec = 'updateValue( "Key_Manager|translateX|transX" )' )


def updateValue (name) :

    name = name.split('|')
    name = name[-1]
    attr = name.split('|')
    attr = name[1]

    cmds.setAttr ("%s + .attr" %selected, textField.tx)`
```

Comment: could you make some executable script with just one textfield. It will be easier for me to help you

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple version of the last upadates I did :

```
import maya.cmds as cmds

wName = "Key_Manager"
selected = cmds.ls(selection=True)

# Make a new window
#
if cmds.window(wName , exists = 1) : cmds.deleteUI(wName)

window = cmds.window( wName, s=0)
form = cmds.formLayout (wName +'Form')

# Translate
#
translateMenu = cmds.text ( l='TranslateX' ,  fn="boldLabelFont")
cmds.formLayout( form , e=1 , attachForm = [ (translateMenu , 'top' , 45) , (translateMenu, 'left' , 50 ) ] )

transX_value = cmds.textField( w=100 , h=22 , tx= cmds.getAttr("%s.translateX" %selected[0]) , ec = 'updateValue( "Key_Manager|translateX|transX" )' )
cmds.formLayout( form , e=1 , attachForm = [ (transX_value , 'top' , 68) , (transX_value , 'left' , 50 ) ] )


# Show Window
cmds.window( wName,e=1)
cmds.showWindow(window)


# Update Value
#
def updateValue (name) :

    name = name.split('|')
    name = name[-1]
    attr = name.split('|')
    attr = name[1]

    cmds.setAttr ("%s + .attr" %selected, name+'_value'.text.getAttr('value'))
```

You'll need to have one object selected to launch it.
Thanks for your help.