# How can I return a textField text as a string value?

Tags: python, maya

So I'm creating a script and I need to input a name in a text field so that it can be applied to a filename.
I created a side script to test out how to do this, however, when I press the button, even though there are no errors, empty space is printed

```
import maya.cmds as cmds

def pritest(*args):
    print(namepull)
#    Create a window with a some fields for entering text.
#
window = cmds.window()
cmds.rowColumnLayout( numberOfColumns=2, columnAttach=(1, 'right', 0), columnWidth=[(1, 100), (2, 250)] )
cmds.text( label='Name' )
#
name = cmds.textField()
cmds.textField(name, e=True,ed=True)
namepull = cmds.textField(name,q=True,tx=True)
#
cmds.button('Go',en=True,c=pritest)

cmds.showWindow( window )
```

I would like for this code to print whatever is typed into de fieldText.
Thanks in advance for any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

also an elegant way is to use partial from functools :

```
import maya.cmds as cmds
from functools import partial

def pritest(fieldname, *args):
    text = cmds.textField(fieldname,q=True,tx=True)
    print(text)

window = cmds.window()
cmds.rowColumnLayout( numberOfColumns=2, columnAttach=(1, 'right', 0), columnWidth=[(1, 100), (2, 250)] )
cmds.text( label='Name' )
name = cmds.textField()
cmds.button('Go',en=True,c=partial(pritest, name))
cmds.showWindow( window )
```

you can see an exemple here too : [Update textField value connected to a setAttr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48451459/update-textfield-value-connected-to-a-setattr/48460932#48460932)

Comment: Thanks! I'll definitely check out this approach next time I write a new script!

Answer (score 1):

`namepull` does only contain the string at the moment you query it what is directly after creation and then it contains nothing. You have to query the field in your pritest function like this:

```
    import maya.cmds as cmds
    
    def pritest(fieldname):
        text = cmds.textField(fieldname,q=True,tx=True)
        print(text)
        
    window = cmds.window()
    cmds.rowColumnLayout( numberOfColumns=2, columnAttach=(1, 'right', 0), columnWidth=[(1, 100), (2, 250)] )
    cmds.text( label='Name' )
    name = cmds.textField()
    cmds.button('Go',en=True,c=lambda x: pritest(name))
    cmds.showWindow( window )
```

I use a lambda function here because this way you do not need to define any global variables to save the field name since you need to know the field name in the pritest function. The best option is to use a class to encapsulate all UI elements.

Comment: Thanks! I'm really new to both python and maya scripting so this helped me a lot. May a ask what the x does in this: `c=lambda x: pritest`

Comment: Not really sure since I do not use lambdas very often, but without, it would not know that the pritest needs a parameter.